# Integral Test on An Open Ball

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, zeta-functions

To show  $\zeta(s)$ is convergent [(click here and go to page 1)](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2018fa/LectureNotes16.pdf), it is written in Definition 16.1. that-

> use the integral test on an open ball strictly to the right of the
>   line $Re(s) = 1$

Now, I understand that $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n \geq 1}n^{-s}$ is convergent when $s=2$ from [this online tutorial of integral test using graph](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx), I assume similary we can prove for $s>2$,  $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n \geq 1}n^{-s}$ is convergent. But I cannot relate this with **integral test on an open ball strictly to the right of the line** $Re(s) = 1$.

Can any one plese elaborately explain how can we use integral test on an open ball strictly to the right of the line $Re(s) = 1$?

Thanks.

Comment: $\sum 1/n^{1.5}$ is also convergent. As are $\sum 1/n^{1.1}$, and $\sum 1/n^{1.01}$, and so on. I think this is more or less what they want you to prove. Try the integral test there. It really shouldn't be too different from $\sum 1/n^2$.

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ is a function, so it's odd to speak of its convergence

Comment: I'm guessing you've covered this at some point: $\sum 1/n^p<\infty$ for every $p>1.$ Proof: Integral test.